# Driver Nvidia 96.43.23 for Quadro 4 wont stay installed

Tags: drivers, nvidia

No matter how many times I re-install my driver it will be uninstalled after restart.

1. I select and install the correct driver using Device Driver Manager by Mint
2. I restart as prompted
3. It comes back up without my driver and switches to some "versa" driver I've never heard    of

3a. Also, I got this error

> Unknown driver error.  Please remove before installing drivers with DDM

I am unsure what that means.  How do I comply with what it is asking?

Comment: Did you tried to remove the drivers with DDM?

Comment: No I didn't,  I don't know what that means...

Comment: Mint is off-topic on Ask Ubuntu because it isn't official. [unix.se] supports it though.

Comment: Not versa but VESA, which is a well known standard.

Comment: Please give some details about how you have installed your drivers. Generally speaking, you are better off installing binary packages (debs) than doing a source based install, because all the configuration will be taken care of. Which method did you use?